# UTL_HTTP working in toad, not as package

Tags: oracle, http, plsql

I am in the process of creating a plsql program that will download images from a web page.
If I run the following code through TOAD, I am getting a HTTP status of 200 (OK). The problem is when running this code as a stored procedure, it is returning a HTTP status of 403 (Forbidden).

```
DECLARE
  req   UTL_HTTP.REQ;
  resp  UTL_HTTP.RESP;
  name  VARCHAR2(256);
  value VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN
  UTL_HTTP.SET_PROXY('example');
  req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('example');
  UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
  resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HTTP response status code: ' || resp.status_code);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HTTP response reason phrase: ' || resp.reason_phrase);
  FOR i IN 1..UTL_HTTP.GET_HEADER_COUNT(resp) LOOP
    UTL_HTTP.GET_HEADER(resp, i, name, value);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(name || ': ' || value);
  END LOOP;
  UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
END;
```

What are the differences in using UTL_HTTP in TOAD (apps login) and as a stored procedure (apps login)?

Comment: That is strange.  You are 100% sure you are sending the same exact request?  Interested to know what is going on.

Comment: Can you access the server logs on the remote server to see if there is any difference in the requests it sees?

Comment: yeah, the only difference is one is in a procedure and one is called from TOAD. I have checked the server logs on the IIS server and do not see the 403 even logged. That is why I believe this is an issue with utl_http.

Comment: This sounds like you are connected to TOAD as a user with higher privileges than the stored procedure. Is the stored procedure in the same schema as the one you are connected through in TOAD?

Comment: Does the user in question have execute permission on the package?

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you ever figured this out? I am having exactly the same issue with this package even if I log into the database as "System" or my user has admin rights. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a stored procedure the code is being executed from the DB server and so the proxy needs to be set on the DB server as well. When running through TOAD is was using the proxy settings on the APPS server.